# Как работает функция argmax в numpy при наличии параметра axis?

Tags: python, numpy

```
>>> a = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3) + 10
>>> a
     array([[10, 11, 12],
           [13, 14, 15]])
>>> np.argmax(a)
 5
>>>np.argmax(a, axis=0)
      array([1, 1, 1])
>>> np.argmax(a, axis=1)
    array([2, 2])
```

Прошу у более опытных товарищей объяснить это поведение функции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По умолчанию ищет индекс максимального элемента(в плоскости), т.е грубо говоря как будто у тебя просто `[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]` `np.argmax(a)` и выводит этот индекс 5.
Когда указывается параметр `axis` ищет относительно осей координат `(0-x, 1-y)`.
По `x` у тебя три значения , вот он и вывел индексы максимальных элементов относительно каждого `х`(их 3). Относительно y их 2 .